# How to validate list of records in a SP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following SQL,

```
  SELECT TD.MyTempTableID
        ,TD.ID
        ,TD.Name
        ,TD.PhoneNumber
        ,TD.Featured
        ,TD.Price
        ,TD.Available
        ,TD.ModelNumber
        ,TD.Searchable
        ,TD.Brand
        ,TD.Tags
        ,TD.ShortDescriptions
        ,TD.Variations
        ,TD.Promotion
        ,TD.Archive
        ,TD.UPC
        ,TD.Status
FROM    MyTempTable YD
WHERE   TD.Brand = @Brand
```

Now I need to validate all fields of all these rows in my SP. How to do this?

Comment: i think you need cursor...it wioll give you each row with which you can validate your data

Comment: @AmitSingh, can you show a example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a column to the temporary table `IsValid BIT DEFAULT(1)`.

Next I would run each validation routine per column:

```
UPDATE MyTempTable
SET IsValid = 0
WHERE IsNumeric(PhoneNumber) = 0
-- don't process rows that have already failed
AND IsValid = 1
```

Repeat the above for each column, replacing the WHERE clause with what would make that value be NOT valid.

Once done, you can query for `WHERE IsValid = 1` to get the rows that passed validation, or `WHERE IsValid = 0` for those that failed one or more tests.

For when you want something to describe why it failed you could add another column `ErrorReason VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT('')`.

```
UPDATE MyTempTable
SET IsValid = 0,
    -- note I'm forcing a line-break here inside the string so each reason is on a new line
    ErrorReason += 'PhoneNumber must be numeric
' 
WHERE IsNumeric(PhoneNumber) = 0
```

Note that in this case we're not including the `AND IsValid = 1` condition, as we want to get multiple reasons for failure. Feel free to add that if you only want the first reason for failure.

Now when you're done, rows with `IsValid = 0` will also have one or more reasons too.

Comment: Good Approach. I like it

Comment: Is it good for repeat update for each column? Measn IsValid for each column?

Comment: Depends if you want multiple failures (only if you're added to `ErrorReason` like my 2nd sample). If you only care about the first reason then you could add another clause to the WHERE: `AND IsValid = 1`, I'll add that to the first example.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @ID as varchar(500)
Declare @Name as varchar(30)
Declare @MOBILE as varchar(20)
 --AND OTHER vARUIABLE FOR oTHER FIELDS
Declare MY_data CURSOR FOR

 SELECT TD.MyTempTableID
        ,TD.ID
        ,TD.Name
        ,TD.PhoneNumber
        ,TD.Featured
        ,TD.Price
        ,TD.Available
        ,TD.ModelNumber
        ,TD.Searchable
        ,TD.Brand
        ,TD.Tags
        ,TD.ShortDescriptions
        ,TD.Variations
        ,TD.Promotion
        ,TD.Archive
        ,TD.UPC
        ,TD.Status
FROM    MyTempTable YD
WHERE   TD.Brand = @Brand

OPEN MY_data
    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_data INTO @ID, @Name ,@MOBILE -- All other Declared vARIABLE FOR EACH COLUMNS EACH SEPERATE BY ','
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
 --Here you can validate data for each row since each row value is stored in vaariables above like
if( ! IsNumeric(@Mobile))
Delete From TableName where Id=@Id

        END
    CLOSE MY_data
DEALLOCATE MY_data
```

Comment: @user960567 the purpose you are asking is only soved by cursor effectively.And slowness i would recmmoend to get right and more accurate results in little high time rather than get wrong on in less time...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of validation you are doing and the expected size of your result set, the indexes on your tables and the size of the original dataset there are several approaches that might work, the simplest being SELECT * into #tmp From TableName Where... then run queries on #tmp to either remove records that don't match or just select the ones that do. Without more details it is difficult to give you a more specific answer.

Forget This Part.
Why not

```
DELETE From Table where ISnumeric(PhoneNumber)=0
```

With appropriate where clauses...

Comment: I misread the usernames above, my apologies.  Cursors are slow and expensive, you should be using where clauses to validate your result set, what kind of validation are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to validate all fields in all rows. For example, required, size limit, foreign key value check, etc.

Comment: Depending on the type of validation you are doing and the expected size of your result set, the indexes on your tables and the size of the original dataset there are several approaches that might work, the simplest being SELECT * into #tmp From TableName Where... then run queries on #tmp to either remove records that don't match or just select the ones that do.  Without more details it is difficult to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: Yes, Cursors are slow---[Performance Tuning SQL Server Cursors](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/cursors/)

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to comment on @timothyWalters answer, but i would suggest adding Where IsValid=1 to each subsequent update if you do them separately, that way you keep shrinking the set instead of evaluating already failed rows.

Answer (score -1):

Are you expecting this type of validation inside your SP

create proc SP_name

begin

Select 
Case when LEN(TD.Name) > 0 then “valid name” else “Invalid” end,
Case when isnumeric(TD.phonenumber) = 0 then “valid” else “Invalid” end,
Case when ……
From table

end